# If I want to develop a search engine,then where I'll get the input data on which I'll apply algorithm to retrieve relevant pages?

Tags: search-engine

I want to develop search engine. But I couldn't get demo data for search engine. I want demo data on which I apply algorithm to retrieve the Web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://www.generatedata.com/) to generate custom dummy data.
You can also 'rip' a few random websites.

You can also create an array with info about the website that is being searched, make the search operable before dynamically adding the website info to the array.